# How to use random input in Selenium IDE using HTML?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

I want create a script in selenium IDE using html. I am not able to set the random/auto generated input in any field(Ex: email address, text, numbers, etc.).
Or I want to increment the input value entered in any field.
Can someone provide me the solution to implement this logic/script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to generate random values and increment numbers as well.

Links on how to use javascript in ide :

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#store-commands-and-selenium-variables

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#javascript-and-selenese-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I just posted [this extension](https://github.com/purefan/tesenfox/blob/master/type_lorem.js) to type a Lorem Ipsum text. The first param is the locator and the second one (optional) tells how many words to type